# JAVA Soap XML response with specific date format

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, soap, datetime-format

I have a web service that retrives an object as XML Response
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

I noticed date is showed as:

```
<myDate>2019-06-03T11:36:19.371+01:00</myDate>
```

but I expect

```
<myDate>2019-06-03T11:36:19</myDate>
```

I know that dateFormat would be a solution but it returns String and I can't set it to my var:

`//myDate is Date type
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/ddTHH:mm:ss");
service.setMyDate(df.format(new Date()))`

Comment: What argument type does `setMyDate` require? Are you unable to change it? If you are using an existing API that formats the date in its own way, I don’t think we’re the right ones to tell you whether you can change that formatting. Search the API documentation or support.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve

```
<myDate>2019-06-03T11:36:19</myDate>
```

from

```
<myDate>2019-06-03T11:36:19.371+01:00</myDate>
```

you can use

```
String dateString = "2019-06-03T11:36:19.371+01:00";
String[] curDate = s.split(".");
String date = curDate[0];
```

Then you can further process the `date` variable.

Comment: in this case: setMyDate(date) would throw error. 
I need set it because I'm sending an object to generate XML, not sending elements one by one.